# Solve a system of equations depending on $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of equations in field $\Bbb R$ depending on the real parameter $\lambda$:

$$\lambda x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=1$$
$$2x_1-x_2-x_4=1$$
$$4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+\lambda x_4=3$$
$$5x_2+2x_3+3x_4=1$$
My attempt:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda &2 &1 &1 | &1\\
2 &-1 &0 &-1 | &1\\
4 &3 &2 &\lambda | &3\\
0 &5 &2 &3 | &1\\
\end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix} 
2 &-1 &0 &-1 |&1\\
\lambda &2 &1 &1 |&1\\
4 &3 &2 &\lambda |&3\\
0 &5 &2 &3| &1\\
\end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix}
2 &-1 &0 &-1 | &1\\
0 &\frac{\lambda+4}{2} &1 &\frac{\lambda+2}{2}| &\frac{2-\lambda}{2}\\
0 &5 &2 &2+\lambda | &1\\
0 &5 &2 &3|&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
2 &-1 &0 &-1| &1\\
0 &\frac{\lambda+4}{2} &1 &\frac{\lambda+2}{2} |&\frac{2-\lambda}{2}\\
0 &5 &2 &2+\lambda | &1\\
0 &0 &0 &1-\lambda| &0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

For $\lambda\neq 1$ the system has no solution. 
For $\lambda=1$ we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 &-1 &0 &-1 |&1\\
0 &\frac{5}{2} &1 &\frac{3}{2} | &\frac{1}{2}\\
0 &5 &2 &3 |&1\\
0 &0 &0&0| &0\\
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
\\2 &0 &\frac{2}{5} &-\frac{2}{5}|&\frac{6}{5}\\
0 &\frac{5}{2} &1 &\frac{3}{2} |& \frac{1}{2}\\
0 &0 &0&0| &0\\
0 & 0 &0 &0| &0
\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}
5 &0 &1 &-1| &3\\
0 &5 &2 &3 |&1\\
0 &0 &0 &0|&0\\
0 &0 &0 &0|&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$
\Rightarrow 5x_1+x_3-x_4=3$$
$$5x_2+2x_3+3x_4=1$$

$$\Rightarrow x_1=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{x_3}{5}+\frac{x_4}{5}$$
$$x_2=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2x_3}{5}-\frac{3x_4}{5}$$

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{5}\\
\frac{1}{5}\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{5}\\
-\frac{2}{5}\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{5}\\
-\frac{3}{5}\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}t,s\in\Bbb R$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you think that for $\lambda\ne 1$ has no solution?

Comment: @mathlover oh no, that's wrong...thanks!

Comment: Determinant of your matrix is non-zero unless $\lambda=1$. Thus for $\lambda\neq1$, you will have a unique solution.

Comment: Looks like $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(0,-1,3,0)$$

Comment: @polfosol Ok, I managed to get the same solution in case where $\lambda\neq 1$. Is what I did above alright for $\lambda=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't solved any similar problems before. But my guess is, it looks like $X$ should be a linear combination of the eigenvectors of the matrix of coefficients (correct me if I am wrong). So with
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda &2 &1 &1\\
2 &-1 &0 &-1\\
4 &3 &2 &\lambda\\
0 &5 &2 &3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
the eigenvectors (for $\lambda=1$) are:
$$\pmatrix{1\\0\\2\\2},\pmatrix{1\\-3\\0\\5},\pmatrix{-1\\-2\\5\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}$$