# Solving a system of linear equations that depends on parameters $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

Solve the system depending on $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$:
$$x_1+2x_2-2x_3=0$$
$$3x_1-2x_2+2x_3=4$$
$$x_1+\alpha x_2+2x_3=2\beta$$

My attempt:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &2 &-2  &0\\
3 &-2 &2  &4\\
1 &\alpha &2  &2\beta
\end{array}\right)\sim\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &2 &-2  &0\\
0 &-8 &8 &4\\
0 &\alpha-2 &4 &2\beta
\end{array}\right)\sim\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &1 &-1 &-\frac{1}{2}\\
0 &0 &\alpha+2 &\frac{\alpha+4\beta -2}{2}
\end{array}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow x_1=1 \\ x_2-x_3=-\frac{1}{2} \\ x_3(\alpha+2)=\frac{\alpha+4\beta -2}{2}$$

If $\alpha=-2\Rightarrow \beta=1\Rightarrow X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-\frac{1}{2}+x_3\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}$

If $\alpha\neq -2 \Rightarrow X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\frac{\beta-1}{\alpha+2}\\
\frac{\alpha+4\beta-2}{2\alpha+4}
\end{pmatrix}, \beta\in \Bbb R$

Is this correct?

Comment: There is at least one case missing, if $\alpha=-2$ and $\beta \ne 1$ then the system has no solutions.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, you're right, but what do you mean at least?

Comment: That meant I'll leave it to you to check if there are any other special cases left (I don't think there are).

Comment: Am I the only one who gets the feeling [that I have seen this before](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2122077/301977)?